# Does "newslet" exist?

Tags: word-request, question-words

I was quite sure I've heard people talking before about "newslets", or "media newslets", but the dictionaries list no such word.

Am I talking about media outlets or something like this? Does the word "newslet" exist (in some spelling variation) or is my brain making it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usual in the English language to "invent" words in order to shorten a sentence, when a dedicated words does not exist, or when one does not remember the word quickly, or when one wants to sound "non-standard" / cool.

There are several ways to do that:

- join two or more words (or word fragments) together;
- adding suffixes;
- misspelling.

Some of these "invented" words actually become "proper", documented in the dictionaries, while others remain just slang / informal.

It seems to be the same case with "newslet" = news + (out)let.